# How to compile a .fs file into a .exe?

Tags: compiler-construction, f#

I do not find a way to compile a simple file (.fs) to a .exe. I tried this example and it does not work:

1. In the file dolphin.fs:

   ```
   let longBeaked = "Delphinus capensis"
   let shortBeaked = "Delphinus delphis"
   let dolphins = [ longBeaked; shortBeaked ]
   printfn "Known Dolphins: %A" dolphins
   ```
2. You can now compile this code to an EXE as shown here:

   ```
   C:\fsharp> fsc dolphins.fs
   C:\fsharp> dir dolphins.exe
   ```

But when I do this an error occurs on the ":" from "C:\fsharp"

Comment: Huh? Where are you calling fsc from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a bit wrong - aside from the fact that you're not supposed to type the first bit (as explained by svick), you probably also need to specify the full path to the F# compiler. If you're using F# that comes with Visual Studio 2010, then you need:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Fsc.exe" dolphins.fs
```

If you're using standalone installation of F#, then you'll need to locate the F# compiler somewhere else (probably in "Program Files (x86)\FSharp-2.0.0.0", but I'm not exactly sure). Also, I'm not sure what is the `dir` command supposed to do. To execute the compiled application (once it is compiled), you can just type:

```
doplhins.exe
```

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Fsc.exe dolphins.fs returns "Unexpected caracter '\'

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft F#\v4.0\Fsc.exe" dolphins.fs returns "this value is not a function and cannot be applied"

Comment: PS : i'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: @katter75 The "value is not a function" error comes from the F# compiler, so this is a good starting point. It seems that you may have some accidental white space in your file or something like that. Can you check the source and post full error message?

Comment: @katter75 - The error messages you're reporting sound like  you're typing a command line into F# interactive. You need to type that stuff at a command prompt, or make and F# Windows Application project in Visual Studio and simply Build it.

Comment: @JoelMueller Aah, that very much sounds like what's going on! I'd suggest posting it as a separate answer - it deserves +1.

Answer (score 4):

You're not supposed to type the whole line. The `C:\fsharp>` part represents the command line prompt. You should just type `fsc dolhins.fs` and then `dir dolphins.exe`.

Comment: when I just type "fsc dolphins.fs" the following error appears : the value or constructor "fsc" is not defined

Comment: You should write that to the Windows command line. And if you are using VS, you can just use its Build command and it should create the exe file automatically, no need for calling `fsc` manually.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages sound like you're typing command-prompt commands into F# interactive.

Try opening the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" from your start menu, changing to the right directory, and typing your commands there.

Alternately, create a new F# Application project in Visual Studio, add your .fs file to the project, and build it.