# Compile F# application to a standalone native executable?

Tags: f#

Is is possible to compile an F# application to a standalone native executable, like a program, or a library for use in other native programs?

If so, can that be done for Windows, Linux and macOS?

Thanks,

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713377/how-to-compile-a-fs-file-into-a-exe) for windows exe files.

Answer (score 12):

According to this [Visual Studio UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/7542181-add-f-support-for-net-native)
 entry, there is currently work in progress for adding F# support to .Net Native:

> Support for F# in the .NET Native compiler is in progress. The F# team, in
>   collaboration with the .NET Native team, has posted an update on their GitHub 
>   which can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/1096.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I will leave this question open until full support for F# native is provided.

Comment: This issue is being followed here now: https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/6055

Answer (score 9):

The upcoming .NET 7 release will [ship with Native AOT](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-7-preview-3/#faster-lighter-apps-with-native-aot):

> Native AOT is similar to .NET’s existing AOT technologies, but it produces only native artifacts. In fact, the Native AOT runtime does not know how to read the .NET assembly file formats – everything is platform-native. The executable file format parsing is fully handled by the underlying operating system.

You can track Native AOT development progress in https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/61231.

Also the F#-to-JS compiler Fable will include a Rust compilation target in its [upcoming release](https://fable.io/blog/2022/2022-06-06-Snake_Island_alpha.html):

> One of the benefits of compiling F# to Rust is to provide an alternative to .NET Native AOT compilation to native binaries, but with a smaller footprint. Another interesting application is that Rust can be compiled to WebAssembly through wasm-pack. This is already possible with F# and Blazor, but as with native applications going through Rust you avoid having to include the whole .NET runtime in your apps.